# Where should one add the js file (D7) to be attached to the custom theme's template.php file

Tags: 7, theming

I have js file which needs to be attached to template.php file.
 
Can I directly add the js file in template.php file ?
I am using drupal_add_js() but
 
should I add it inside the functions of template.php 
or 
should I add it directly into template.php file
I have the code in d6 which has added the drupal_add_js() in template.php file
 
without including it in any of the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

In Drupal 7, you can achieve it by

- Using preproccess function([theme_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7))

  ```
  function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      //check your condition and add js here
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/mytheme.js', 'file'); //if js file is in theme folder
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE_NAME') .'/js/myscript.js', 'file'); //if js file is in module folder
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Quick example of use in your theme's template.php

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/mytheme.js', 'file');
}
```

Reference : https://api.drupal.org/comment/14344#comment-14344